# How to prove that a $\phi \in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$.

Tags: functions, derivatives, convergence-divergence

I would like to prove that the function, defined as:

\begin{equation}
\phi(x)=\begin{cases} e^{-1/x}, & x>0 \\
0 , & x \leq 0\end{cases}
\end{equation}

is a $C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$. So far I have showed that, for a $k=\{1,2,...n \}\in \mathbb{N}$, the derivative for $k$-ith order of $\phi$, for all $x>0$, can be written as:

\begin{equation}
\phi^{(k)}(x)=x^{-(k+1)}p_k(x)\phi(x)
\end{equation}
where $p_k(x)$ are polynomials of negative order $m$. Now I should just let $k \to \infty$ and prove that the limit:
\begin{equation}
\lim_{k \to \infty}\phi^{(k)}(x)
\end{equation}
exists. Is that correct? And if yes, I just find that the limit will be equal to zero. Does this hold as a decent proof of the original request? Or should I try to prove that by a method of induction?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: @Shalop Well, I searched for a while, but the closest is the demand for a $\phi$ to be $C^{\infty}_{0}(\mathbb{R})$. Can you find another similar to this one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right track. In order to make it formal, what you should do is generalize the claim to

> **Lemma.** Let $k$ be a nonnegative integer. Then for every integer $m$ and for every real polynomial $P$, the function $$x\mapsto\begin{cases} 0 & x\le 0 \\ \frac{P(x)}{x^m}e^{-1/x} & x>0 \end{cases} $$ is $\mathcal C^k$.

**Proof.** By induction on $k$ ... *bla bla bla. (In the induction step, show that the* first *derivative has the same form,  and is therefore $\mathcal C^{k-1}$ by the induction hypothesis).*

**Corollary.** The function in the lemma, with $m=0$ and $p(x)=1$, is $\mathcal C^\infty$.

---

Alternatively, you could structure essentially the same proof as:

> **Slightly different lemma.** The set of functions of the form $$x\mapsto\begin{cases} 0 & x\le 0 \\ \frac{P(x)}{x^m}e^{-1/x} & x>0 \end{cases} $$ where $m$ is an integer and $P$ is a real polynomial, is closed under differentiation (in particular they are all differentiable and continuous).
>
> **Additional lemma.** Let $\mathcal F$ be a set of differentiable functions that is closed under differentiation. Then $\mathcal F\subseteq \mathcal C^\infty$.
>
> **Corollary.** By the two lemmas, the $e^{-1/x}[x>0]$ function is $\mathcal C^\infty$.

Comment: So in the first step I find: \begin{equation}  \phi'(x)=\frac{P_1(x)}{x^{m}}e^{-1/x}\end{equation}, where $P_1(x)=P'(x)-x^{-1}P(x)(m+1)$ a polynomial that arises from the differentiation. On the $k+1$ step, I showed the same result, just by differentiating the $\phi^{(k)}(x)$ one more time and assuming the new polynomial as the $P_{k+1}(x)$ one. Then it holds,  right? And for function to be $C^{\infty}$, I just let $k \to \infty$?

Comment: @Mitscaype: More or less -- your $P_1$ is not necessarily a polynomial due to the $x^{-1}$ factor (that's what the $x^m$ denominator is there to absorb), and you have forgotten the $\frac{P(x)}{x^m}\cdot\frac{d}{dx}e^{-1/x}$ term from the outer product rule, but the general principle is right. And you need to add in an ad-hoc argument that the function is _once_ differentiable at $0$.

Comment: You don't need to "let $k\to 0$" (and I'm not sure that actually describes something that makes sense here). Just argue that the function is $\mathcal C^k$ for every $k$, which is _the definition_ of what it means to be $\mathcal C^\infty$.

Comment: I cannot delete the comment but you are right, I did made a mistake on the outer product. Thank you again for your help. After proving the Lemma I must just argue that it holds for every $k$ and that would be enough. Thank you again